# USB 2.0 Pogo connect to programmer board across 5mm gap

Tags: usb-device, high-speed

I am looking to make a 5mm connection from a programmer board to another board with USB 2.0 on it through some pogo pins. Could something like this work for the high speed over a short distance? Any other good solutions to clear the gap? Anybody have solutions for a simmilar problem?

If that doesn't work what about a USB 1.1 connection?

[image]
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mill-max-manufacturing-corp/0914-0-15-20-77-14-11-0/1147053

Comment: When you say USB 2.0, are you referring specifically to USB 2.0 High Speed (the 480 Mbps protocol)? Or does this device need only Full Speed (12 Mbps) or even Low Speed (1.5 Mbps)? The USB 1.1 speeds (Full and Low) are pretty resilient to that kind of stuff, but High Speed tends to be picky about impedance matching.

Comment: Full speed 2.0i s 480mbps, I would like to run it at 480 Mbps but if I can't I can settle for 12 Mbps with the USB 1.2

Comment: I believe that's USB 1.1; I don't think there ever was a 1.2. But you should almost certainly be able to get 12 Mbps, and you might manage more (I'm not sure if it's possible to run the bus at intermediate speeds).

Comment: Yeah I was definitely off, I'll edit

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need to be up to spec, just good enough to work in practice.

Avoid stubs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLS2ob.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The host PHY should be close to the pogo pins. The pogo test points/pads should be close to the upstream facing port connector (UFP) on the device.

The overall idea is that the HOST-POGO-UFP_socket combo is compact and is approximated by lumped parasitics, whereas the traces from all that to the device's PHY/SoC can be a transmission line.

In many devices all the traces are so short that it doesn't matter all that much anyway.

The first time I tried it a couple years ago, it worked, so I can't really say whether I got very lucky, or if the physical layer is just robust enough to deal with such abuse.